# Get the Pod which has the maximum CPU usage

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to sort the pod by maximum CPU usage. I know there is a lot of tools which comes with monitoring. I would like to find this by using 'kubectl top' command.

any help is appreciated - thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can run the below command to sort all pods across all namespaces by their cpu utilization.

```
kubectl top po -A --sort-by=cpu
```

Answer (score 12):

For a general command that gives usage see [stackoverflow.com/a/64025079/2746623](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64025079/2746623). On unix I was doing `kubectl top pod | sort -k2 -n` but the linked answer is more general.

That'll tell you usage but if you want allocation (based on requests and limits) then you might instead want `kubectl describe nodes`. There's a [github thread with some further suggestions and discussion](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/17512).

Comment: This answer is not correct. Look at this answer instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/64025079/2746623

Comment: @opentokix Thanks for pointing this out. I realise now that my answer was unix-specific and have changed it to point to the more general one as that is the better answer

Answer (score 2):

`$ kubectl top pods --all-namespaces  --sort-by cpu`

Answer (score 1):

You can use
k top pods -A --sort-by=cpu | head -4 // it will show with headers,
so need head -4.

k top pods -A --sort-by=cpu --no-headers | head -3 //print without headercolumns
**OR**

//To get top 3 pods
k top pods | sort --reverse --numeric --key 2 | head -3

refer all imperative commands here-:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#top
also u can run below cmd to get understanding with examples -:
k top --help